# Java (android) - RSS Parse to ListView, Error?? (Android Development)

Tags: java, android, rss, blogger

I'm newbie(beginner) in android development, I have blog on **Blogger.com** and wanted to get RSS data and parse it to Android ListView, when I'm using, for example https://www.sammobile.com/feeds/ it works, but when I change url adress to my blog rss adress: https://mystat115.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default   it doesn't anything at all.. just blank activity...

Here is code that I used too...

**Article.Java**

```
public class Article {

String title,description;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

**Connector.Java**

```
public class Connector {

public static Object connect(String urlAddress)
{
    try
    {
        URL url=new URL(urlAddress);
        HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        con.setReadTimeout(15000);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        return con;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ErrorTracker.WRONG_URL_FORMAT;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ErrorTracker.CONNECTION_ERROR;
    }
}
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context c;
ArrayList<Article> articles;

public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Article> articles) {
    this.c = c;
    this.articles = articles;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return articles.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return articles.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
    }

    TextView titleTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
    TextView descTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descTxt);

    final Article article= (Article) this.getItem(position);

    titleTxt.setText(article.getTitle());
    descTxt.setText(article.getDescription().substring(0, 120));

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(c, article.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

**Downloader.java**

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Object> {

Context c;
String urlAddress;
ListView lv;

ProgressDialog pd;

public Downloader(Context c, String urlAddress, ListView lv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
    this.lv = lv;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Fetch data");
    pd.setMessage("Fetching Data...Please wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.downloadData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object data) {
    super.onPostExecute(data);
    pd.dismiss();

    if(data.toString().startsWith("Error"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,data.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        //PARSE
        new RSSParser(c, (InputStream) data,lv).execute();
    }
}

private Object downloadData()
{
    Object connection=Connector.connect(urlAddress);
    if(connection.toString().startsWith("Error"))
    {
        return connection.toString();
    }

    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode==con.HTTP_OK)
        {
            InputStream is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            return is;
        }

        return ErrorTracker.RESPONSE_ERROR+con.getResponseMessage();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ErrorTracker.IO_EROR;
    }
}


  }
```

**ErrorTracker.java**

```
public class ErrorTracker {

public final static String WRONG_URL_FORMAT="Error : Wrong URL Format";
public final static String CONNECTION_ERROR="Error : Unable To Establish Connection";
public final static String IO_EROR="Error : Unable To Read";
public final static String RESPONSE_ERROR="Error : Bad Response - ";

}
```

**RSSParser.java**

```
public class RSSParser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

Context c;
InputStream is;
ListView lv;

ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<Article> articles=new ArrayList<>();

public RSSParser(Context c, InputStream is, ListView lv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.is = is;
    this.lv = lv;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Parse data");
    pd.setMessage("Parsing Data...Please wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parseRSS();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isParsed) {
    super.onPostExecute(isParsed);

    pd.dismiss();
    if(isParsed)
    {
        //BIND
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(c,articles));
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable To Parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private Boolean parseRSS()
{
    try
    {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser=factory.newPullParser();

        parser.setInput(is,null);
        int event=parser.getEventType();

        String value=null;
        articles.clear();
        Article article=new Article();

        do {

            String name=parser.getName();

            switch (event)
            {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(name.equals("item"))
                    {
                        article=new Article();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    value=parser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if(name.equals("title"))
                    {
                        article.setTitle(value);
                    }else if(name.equals("description"))
                    {
                        article.setDescription(value);
                    }
                    if(name.equals("item"))
                    {
                        articles.add(article);
                    }

                    break;
            }

            event=parser.next();

        }while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);

        return true;

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

and **MainActivity.java**

```
 ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    new Downloader(MainActivity.this,urlAddress,lv).execute();
```

Please, any solution? Keep in mind, it's blogger rss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `?alt=rss` to blogspot feed url :

```
https://mystat115.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss
```

Answer (score 0):

A few notes: your RSS is using an Atom format so make sure your code based on that. [Atom specifications](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/atom.html)

For a step by step guide to implementing RSS parsing, check out this amazing guide from [Androoid documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml).